# How to capture scaffold-eth Transactor error

Tags: transactions, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I am using [scaffold-eth's Transactor](https://docs.scaffoldeth.io/scaffold-eth/toolkit/scaffold-eth-toolbox/eth-services) to send transactions. But I am not able to capture if an error (or revert) occurs after the transaction is send. Instead I am getting `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wait')` because the tx is undefined if an error occurs. How can I capture the transaction error? Below is my code:

```
// scaffold-eth's Transactor helper gives us a nice UI popup when a transaction is sent. Transactor is a function.
const transactor = Transactor(provider, gasPrice);
const tx = await transactor(contract.redeem(ownerAddress, 0, voucher, {value: amount}));
//Here the tx is undefined since the transaction reverted (failed)
// Wait for the transaction to be confirmed, then get the token ID out of the emitted Transfer event.
const receipt = await tx.wait();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you wrap your code in a try catch?
Something like this:

```
try {
  const tx = await transactor(contract.redeem(ownerAddress, 0, voucher, {value: amount}));
  const receipt = tw.wait(1)
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactor takes a [callback](https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth/blob/3b27c1dd3fe8a9bc612a7094c5c732856c90674b/packages/react-app/src/helpers/Transactor.js#L148) function, passing the callback will catch any sort of transaction error.

```
const tx = await transactor(contract.redeem(ownerAddress, 0, voucher, {value: amount}),(error)=>console.log(error);
```